# how to generate auto numbering based on the form data

Tags: python, mysql

My forms are dynamic forms that generate like inquiry, application & admission form and I am saving data in a single table. But for the form data need to give ids in sequence based on forms like inquiry & etc. like 1st inquiry INQ01/1st application APP01 etc..

1st inquiry INQ01/1st application APP01 etc..`enter code here`if display_form.module.module == 'inquiries':
                count_in = SavedForms.objects.filter(dynamic_forms_id =43).count()
                count_inquries = ++count_in

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us a part of your code

Comment: You don't need to store this. (As long as there are no deletions) It can be inferred from just a regular AI id.